# Can't set values on `process.env` in client-side Javascript

Tags: javascript, environment-variables

I have a system (it happens to be Gatsby, but I don't believe that's relevant to this question) which is using webpack DefinePlugin to attach some EnvironmentVariables to the global variable: `process.env`

I can read this just fine.

Unfortunatley, due to weirdnesses in the app startup proces, I <del>need</del> have chosen to do some brief overwritting of those EnvironmentVariables after the site loads. (Not interested in discussing whether that's the best option, in the context of this question. I know there are other options; I want to know whether *this* is possible)

But it doesn't work :(

---

If I try to do it explicitly:

```
process.env.myVar = 'foo';
```

Then I get `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side`.

---

If I do it by indexer (which appears to be what `dotenv` does) then it doesn't error, but also doesn't work:

```
console.log(process.env.myVar);
process.env['myVar'] = 'foo';
console.log(process.env.myVar);
```

will log `undefined` twice.

---

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Even if you get it to work. The local change of the `process.env` variable won't effect the global environment. So if you need it in another script it won't work anyway using this way.

Comment: Browsers don't provide access to environment variables, so it doesn't make sense to try to do this client side.

Comment: @Quentin You're sort of right, except that they kinda make it *look* like the do, but not really ;) see detailed answer submitted below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The premise behind this attempted solution was flawed.

I was under the impression that webpack "made process.env.* available as an object in the browser".

***It doesn't!***

What it actually does is to transpile you code down into literals wherever you reference `process.env`. So what looks like `fetch(process.env.MY_URL_VAR)`; isn't in fact referencing a variable, it's actually being transpiled down into `fetch("http://theActualValue.com")` at compile time.

That means that it's conceptually impossible to modify the values on the "`process.env` object", because there is not in fact an actual object, in the transpiled javascript.

---

This explains why the direct assignment gives a ref error (you tried to execute `"someString" = "someOtherString";`) but the indexer doesn't. (I assume that `process.env` gets compiled into some different literal, which technically supports an indexed setter)

---

The only solutions available would be to modify the webpack build process (not an option, though I will shortly raise a PR to make it possible :) ), use a different process for getting the Env.Vars into the frontEnd (sub-optimal for various other reasons) or to hack around with various bits of environment control that Gatsby provides to make it all kinda-sorta work (distasteful for yet other reasons).

Comment: Note for reference, that in ***Node.js*** `process.env` really IS just a global object, and CAN be manipulated in exactly this way indeed, that's what `dotenv` is doing. But browsers aren't running Node ;)

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I was wracking my brain trying to figure out why it wouldn't let me assign to it like when I'm working with Node. I'll keep searching for better ways to do my testing.