# Why can't I assign a new variable to process.env?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

The following code is being executed inside of a mocha test:

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('remote api config widget', () => {

// Passes
    it('returns empty string if VUE_APP_API_ROOT is not defined', () => {
        if ('VUE_APP_API_ROOT' in process.env) {
            delete process.env.VUE_APP_API_ROOT;
        }

        let remoteConfig = require('../../../src/api/remoteConfig');
        let result = remoteConfig.default.getRemoteUri();
        expect(result).to.equal('');
    });

// Fails - see console output below!
    it('returns the uri string defined if VUE_APP_API_ROOT is defined', () => {
        const rootUri = 'http://12.34.56.78';
        process.env['VUE_APP_API_ROOT'] = rootUri;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(process.env));
        console.log('DEBUG: VUE_APP_API_ROOT has been set to: ' + process.env.VUE_APP_API_ROOT);
        let remoteConfig = require('../../../src/api/remoteConfig');
        let result = remoteConfig.default.getRemoteUri();
        expect(result).to.equal(rootUri);
    });
});
```

The console output is as follows:

```sh
{"NODE_ENV":"test","BASE_URL":"/"}
DEBUG: VUE_APP_API_ROOT has been set to: undefined
```

Why isn't the new property, VUE_APP_API_ROOT being picked up in the very next statement? Am I missing something special about process.env?

Comment: It works for me (copy/pasted your snippet into a file and ran it). And the [NodeJS docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env) also say it should work

Comment: no there is nothing wrong with your code! I copied and pasted it in a sandbox and it worked correctly. maybe mocha is making trouble

Comment: works as expected, there must be something else that's not shown causing an issue

Comment: So what could be causing this? Its a straight mocha test?

Comment: Is this set of lines written exactly as you posted, in your mocha test (same order and nothing between them)?

Comment: correct, same order, nothing inbetween, all in an `it('',() => {})` statement

Comment: @blex I added the entire file into the original question

Comment: I have a hunch that this is webpack related. When I used the Vue Webpack configs and entered a provided env file, I now get `invalid left-hand assignment` when trying to set process.env. That led me to this SO question that points me towards transpiles process.env: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871895/cant-set-values-on-process-env-in-client-side-javascript